Trying to run a query but throws error unrecognized name even thought query syntax is correct
I am taking a analytics course on coursera and the video instructor executed the following query:
SELECT
  Date,
  Region,
  Small_Bags,
  Large_Bags,
  XLarge_Bags,
 Total_Bags,
 Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XLarge_Bags AS Total_Bags_Calc
 FROM
 `yourproject1234.avocado_data.avocado_prices`

When I executed this query it did not work for me and I received an error:

Unrecognized name: Small_Bags; Did you mean Small Bags? at [4:3]

I looked at the schema to see if I made a spelling mistake but everything seems correct, I rewrote the query again and the same error appears.
How can I make this query work?

It seems clear that the column name uses a space, not an underline.

Hi Tim, I removed the underline and I still get the same error message, in the video the instructor was able to successfully run it as is. The error appears at Small_Bags.

Please update your question with the DDL for the table

Delimit the column name, including its space. (I.e. do not replace space with underscore.)

Thank you for your comments, unfortunately the error problem still arises, I even deleted and re-uploaded the dataset into my project and the same problem appears.  In regards to DDL do you mean dataset information? Preview of the data? Any help is greatly appreciated!

DDL means the CREATE statement for the table

SELECT * FROM yourproject1234.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'avocado_prices'


Why do you think this does anything at all?
